# Is $A \leq B$ with probability $p>1/2$ a partial order on random variables?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, order-theory

It seems reflexive, antisymmetric and transitive. My mathematics training is limited though and I would love proof or contradiction. A quick search turns up many references cataloging on stochastic orderings - e.g. stochastic dominance, hazard rate order, etc. None so far seems to mention this most basic one though.

Is the relation defined as $(A,B) \in \leq_q$ if $p(A  \leq B) \geq q$ a partial order too? I feel like it should be - at least for $q>1/2$, and maybe assuming something about the dependence between any pair $A,B$? - but need help to prove it.

Comment: Reminds me of intransitive dice https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive_dice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, as it is not anti-symmetric.

Anti-symmetry requires that $a≤b\,\,\&\,\,b≤a\implies a=b$.

To get a counter example in your case, suppose that $A\in \{0,1\}$ with probabilities $\{.99,\, .01\}$ and $B\in \{0,2\}$ also with probabilities $\{.99,\, .01\}$  Then, following your definition we see that $A≤B$ and $B≤A$ yet they are not the same variable.

More broadly, you get $A≤B$ and $B≤A$ any time $A=B$ with probability $>\frac 12$, yet that relation does not imply equality of the variables, even if you interpret "equality" to mean "identical distribution".

Comment: For my first question: "Is $A \leq B$ (pointwise) a partial order on random variables?", I was thinking:
Reflexive: A random variable A is pointwise less than or equal to itself.
Antisymmetric: If A is pointwise less than or equal to B and B is pointwise less than or equal to A, then A and B are equal almost everywhere (i.e., except possibly on a set of probability zero).
Transitive: If A is pointwise less than or equal to B and B is pointwise less than or equal to C, then A is pointwise less than or equal to C.

Comment: But, you can see from my explicit example that it doesn't work out, right?

Comment: Apologies for possible naivity but I was expecting us to need some assumptions about the *joint* distribution of A,B in order to calculate $p(A \leq B)$. By pointwise I was thinking $A(\omega) \leq B(\omega)$.

Comment: In the example I gave it doesn't really matter, but assume independence.  So the joint distribution is simply the product.  Thus $P(A=B)=.99^2=.9801$. The least it could be, even with dependence, would be $.98$ which is why I say possible dependence really doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Should say:  it's not clear what you mean by "pointwise".  I just assumed you meant $A≤B$ iff $P(A≤B)>\frac 12$, and my example obviously satisfies that.

Comment: I'm probably missing something. I was thinking $A \leq B$ can only be true pointwise for all realizations/outcomes ($\omega$) if the outcome $(A,B)=(1,0)$ has probability zero.

Comment: sorry for not being clear. By pointwise I meant with probability 1 or almost surely. I was thinking of A,B as functions, i.e. RVs and therefore comparable pointwise. The second half of the question was about >1/2

Comment: Well...you need to edit your post to explain that.  Nobody would ever guess that definition. I just answered the question in the header, as did the other user who posted a (perfectly valid) counterexample.  And for continuous distributions you can still find a contradiction to anti-symmetry, along the same lines as I did.  You just need the exception sets to be possible with probability $0$.

Comment: Let $A$ be uniform on $[0,1]$ and let $A=B$ unless $A=.5$ in which case $B=0$.  Then $P(A=B)=1$ but they are not the same variable.  But, please edit your post for clarity or ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. And apologies for not being crystal clear. You are right, this is really two questions. I will ask another.

Comment: I opened a new question here. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780175/is-a-leq-b-pointwise-a-partial-order

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe your definition will work.

Here's a counter-example:  [Efron's non-transitive dice](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EfronsDice.html#:%7E:text=Efron%27s%20dice%20are%20set%20of,1%20odds%20for%20winning%20pairs.).

Consider four six-sided non-standard dice with the following markings on each side:

- A:  {1,2,3,9,10,11}
- B:  {0,1,7,8,8,9}
- C:  {5,5,6,6,7,7}
- D:  {3,4,4,5,11,12}

If you roll A versus B, you'll find that more than 50% of the time A beats B.  And B beats C.  And C beats D.  And D beats A.

You might wish to look into an extension of this idea, my *[Lake Wobegon Dice](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.4169/college.math.j.43.2.152)*.

Comment: many thanks. very interesting and helpful.